# How often should I change the lines and sail attachment rings?

Tags: gear, sailing

Last fall I bought a [sunfish,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunfish_(sailboat)) best I can tell is built in about 1974 (43 years ago) and has all original sails, sail rings (*hold the sail to the spars*), tiller, etc.  Everything but the lines seem to be original.

Yesterday it was sunny and warm, wind at about 9MPH, 15KPH, 8 Knots. I took it out to the lake for the first time since I got it.  The was a lull as I launched and things went very well.  On my third upwind leg (*narrow lake*) I got good wind and was on beam reach doing about 15MPH, then **the outhauls and sail rings started breaking.** This was something of a distraction, shore rapidly approaching, so I got a chance to practice my self recovery skills, when I tipped it over.

After getting the boat upright, I was able to sail back to shore.

I notice that several places sell "Sunfish Tune-A-Fish Kit" which includes Lines, sail rings, etc. Presumably there is some recommended frequency for changing out gear.

How often should line, sail rings, etc be changed?

Comment: I suspect you know this reply is coming, and I hate to be the one who says it, but the frequency of changes depend on a great deal. Where you store the Sunfish (indoor/outdoor), whether you race or purely recreational, number of times you go out in a season, etc. My advice would simply be change the gear, and then inspect before and after each time out. Replace as you feel it is required.

Comment: @DanPriest that is kind of what I found on several forum posts.  I was hoping for more.  I would expect that everything should have a life expectancy that can measured in hours of sun, or years of use, or something.

Comment: Yes, it would be very handy that way, but there are just too many factors to consider for putting a life expectancy on rigging. Wish I could be more helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have always taught sailing students to run a full check every time they rig the boat (if it's a dinghy or the mast is regularly lowered) or annually before returning it to the water after winter.

Additionally, a full check after any collision or incident, or after heavy weather/storms is recommended.

The problem is that while you can look for worn rigging, it can be very difficult to see problems in areas above your eye-line, or within booms/mast, and deterioration varies due to conditions, storage, sailing stresses, etc so is unpredictable.